# Mapping to multiple data types in ElasticSearch using C# Nest

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-5

Before I dedicate the time to do this, I'm checking if anyone knows of a feature that will allow me to do something a bit more dynamic with Elastic using C#/NEST

We have a situation where we will be receiving data in a field called "Value". That value is a string but it could represent a number, boolean, string, and so on...

I would like to store that on Elastic like the following...

```
item.value  (the value that our system received)
item.value.boolean  (the boolean if it can be converted)
item.value.integer (the integer if it can be converted)
```

I'd like to put the values in as the value to allow the values to be indexed to allow reporting to take place.

I know that I could create multiple .net properties on the object with each datatype represented but I'd prefer an attribute type solution where I could just mark one property and it would create the multiple fields on Elastic.

Does anyone know of a pre-built solution? I know with some effort I could create my own code to write this out but I'd prefer to not spend a day or two writing that out.

Comment: Is it possible for the sending code to send you the value in a different field? You could accomplish this with a ScriptProcessor on ingest: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/script-processor.html but would recommend benchmarking against in-application solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately, we will have 100+ services sending data to our application so it would be like herding cats to get them to send to correct field. It is easier to tell them all to just send to one common field and our application can sort it out.

Thanks for  the script suggestion but I think I would rather implement on the .NET side to allow for more flexibility and performance.